# Javascript Remoting to display a table of records

Tags: apex, javascript, javascript-remoting

Have been trying to learn Javascript Remoting since hours. I have manipulated this [example](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) to display a table of records with remoting an apex class.
Following is the controller and VF.. My controller pulls all records from custom object Feedback. But i'm unable to display in VF. Please guide.

```
 global with sharing class AccountRemoter {

 public String accountName { get; set; }
 public Feedback__c account { get; set; }
 public AccountRemoter() { }

 @RemoteAction
 global static List<Feedback__c> getAccount(String accountName) {
 List<Feedback__c> account = [SELECT Name FROM Feedback__c ];
 return account;
 }
 }
```

and the Visualforce page...

```
 <apex:page controller="AccountRemoter">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function getRemoteAccount() {
    var accountName = document.getElementById('acctSearch').value;

    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.AccountRemoter.getAccount}',
        accountName, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                // Get DOM IDs for HTML and Visualforce elements like this
                document.getElementById('remoteAcctId').innerHTML = result.Id
                document.getElementById(
                    "{!$Component.block.blockSection.secondItem.acctNumEmployees}"
                    ).innerHTML = result.NumberOfEmployees;
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                    event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
            }
         }, 
         {escape: true}
     );
   }
  </script>

    <input id="acctSearch" type="text"/>
    <button onclick="getRemoteAccount()">Get Feedbacks</button>
    <div id="responseErrors"></div>

    <apex:pageBlock id="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="blockSection" columns="2">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="firstItem">
            <span id="remoteAcctId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="secondItem">
            <apex:outputText id="acctNumEmployees"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:page>
```

The closest to a table on click of the "Get Feedback" button, I have achieved so far with  undefined results....
[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE: Fields in Feedback

Client_Feedback_App__c

Description__c

Importance__c

Resolution__c

Status__c

Summary__c

Comment: Does Feedback__c contains feid "NoOfEmployees"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I update the question. There is no field called "NoOfEmployees"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here should be error:

```
result.NumberOfEmployees; // This exists in example you have copied not in your sObject
```

You don't have this field in custom object. Instead try any field which exists in custom object fields and query that field in SOQL also ex:

```
result.Name;
```

Just do this, replace alert(JSON.stringify(result)) with:

```
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
     var name= result[i].Name; // Name is field api name
     alert(name)  ; // or do whatever you want with 
}
```

Comment: Replacing NumberOfEmployees with Name has no effect!

Comment: @MnZ can you `alert` the `result` like `alert(result.toString());`

Comment: OK, I will try.

Comment: on adding alert(result.toString()); to the code I recieved...object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object

Comment: Ok. Can you alert this `alert(JSON.stringify(result));` this should work

Comment: Yes @regal It is showing all the records after I added that. So what does it mean?

Comment: it means you are receiving correct response but may be using it in wrong way. can you post string you got with few records by adding limit to your query for now? @MnZ

Comment: I tried that already. If I modify as List<Feedback__c> account = [SELECT Name FROM Feedback__c limit:1]; I get two columns with undefined, undefined values. I don't where I'm going wrong :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13900/discussion-between-mnz-and-regal)

Comment: I have updated answer @MnZ

Comment: I get the first record's name if I add your for loop for(i=0;i<result.length;i++) { 
var name= result[i].Name; 
alert(name) ;
}

Comment: moved to chat. @MnZ